# Why we are studying Dirac measure?

Tags: measure-theory

If we are doing mathematics for sth worthwhile not just for fun then why do we deed to work on Dirac measure $\delta_x$ at a point $x$? For an arbitrary measure space $(X,\scr{A},\delta_x)$, where $\delta_x$ is defined by:
$$
\delta_{x}(E)= \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if } x \in{E}\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$

Then for any measurable function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $\int_{X}f\,d\delta_x=f(x)$. It is not giving any new results though we are studying this measure. Why?

Comment: Sometimes a measure comes up, and sometimes it's the Dirac measure. I want a word for "ant" so that when I see an ant I can tell my neighbor "hey, it looks like we have ants."

Comment: Because it gives new results.  For example, it may make it easier to compute a Fourier transform.